# Flutter Package Issue: "Target file not found" when running 'flutter run'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, package

I am working on developing a Flutter package designed to create a messenger chat head in the background. The package structure is as follows:

```
Flutter_Head/
|-- lib/
|   |-- flutter_head.dart
|-- test/
|   |-- flutter_head_test.dart
|-- pubspec.yaml
|-- README.md
```

- Flutter version: 1.13.6.8
- Dart version: 2.3.2

I am encountering an issue when trying to run my Flutter package using the flutter run command. The error message I receive is:

> Target file "lib/main.dart" not found.

**Code Samples:**

lib/flutter_head.dart

```
// lib/flutter_head.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlutterHead extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterHead({super.key});

  @override
  _FlutterHeadState createState() => _FlutterHeadState();
}

class _FlutterHeadState extends State<FlutterHead> {
  bool _isChatHeadVisible = true; // Track chat head visibility

  final _appLifecycleObserver = AppLifecycleObserver();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(_appLifecycleObserver);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(_appLifecycleObserver);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isChatHeadVisible
        ? Positioned(
            bottom: 16.0,
            right: 16.0,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: _handleTap,
              child: Container(
                width: 56.0,
                height: 56.0,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.message,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container(); // Return an empty container if chat head is not visible
  }

  void _handleTap() {
    _minimizeApp();
  }

  void _minimizeApp() {
    setState(() {
      _isChatHeadVisible = false; // Hide the chat head
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // App is in the foreground
      // Show the chat head
      _showChatHead();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // App is in the background
      // Hide the chat head
      _hideChatHead();
    }
  }

  void _showChatHead() {
    setState(() {
      _isChatHeadVisible = true; // Show the chat head
    });
  }

  void _hideChatHead() {
    setState(() {
      _isChatHeadVisible = false; // Hide the chat head
    });
  }
}

class AppLifecycleObserver extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
}
```

test/flutter_head_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_head/flutter_head.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('FlutterHead should be visible', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our widget and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const FlutterHead());

    // Verify that the chat head is initially visible.
    expect(find.byType(FlutterHead), findsOneWidget);
  });

  testWidgets('Tapping on FlutterHead should minimize the app',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our widget and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const FlutterHead());

    // Tap on the chat head.
    await tester.tap(find.byType(FlutterHead));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that the app is minimized (chat head is no longer visible).
    expect(find.byType(FlutterHead), findsNothing);
  });
}
```

example/lib/main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_head/flutter_head.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Head Example'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: FlutterHead(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error message

[image]

How to resolve the "**Target file not found**" issue when running flutter run? If there are specific configurations or steps that need attention, please provide detailed instructions.

Comment: If you specify the path explicitly: `flutter run -t example/lib/main.dart` does it work?

Comment: when I specify the path he show me this message: `Changing current working directory to: /Users/newmac/Desktop/My Work/Latest/flutter_head
No devices found yet. Checking for wireless devices...`
after this when I choose **enable android for this project**
he show me this error:
flutter create --platforms android .
The "--platforms" argument is not supported in package template.
exit code 2

Comment: Have you connected your PC to your device properly? You can check if there are ready devices by running `flutter devices`

Comment: after run ```flutter devices``` !
this is the **result**:
Found 3 connected devices:
  STK L21 (mobile) 
  macOS (desktop)  
  Chrome (web)

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing `flutter run` from the parent folder (`Flutter_Head`), specify the target path explicitly:

```
flutter run -t example/lib/main.dart
```

About the `-t` flag:

> -t, --target=                                          The main entry-point file of the application, as run on the device.
> If the "--target" option is omitted, but a file name is provided on the command line, then that is used instead.
> (defaults to "lib\main.dart")

Comment: Same! nothing changes.